# Electromagnetic Induction Problem

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

[image]

I am getting two different answers from two different methods for this problem, which is to find the potential difference between the points A and B, if the rod is rotated anticlockwise. OAB is a rigid rod. 
Now, the EMF developed across the ends of a rotating conductor is given by-
$$e=\dfrac{b\omega l^2}{2}$$ where *l* is the $\textbf{vector length}$ of the conductor.
Now, my problem is- If we calculate the potential difference between O and A by this method, we get- $$V_O-V_A=\dfrac{B\omega 4^2}{2}=8B\omega$$
and if we calculate the same between O and B, we get-
$$V_O-V_B=\dfrac{B\omega 5^2}{2}=12.5B\omega$$

So far so good. Now, I know that the emf developed across a conductor moving in a magnetic field is given by- $$=\displaystyle \int \textbf{v} \times \textbf{B} \cdot \textbf{dl} $$. If we use this formula for conductor AB, its length is parallel to $\textbf{v}$ which should give the integral as 0. Thus $V_A=V_B$ which can not be right by the previous results. Which result is right? Where did I go wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the fallacy lies in using this equation $V_O-V_A=\dfrac{B\omega 4^2}{2}=8B\omega$ because $OB$ doesn't have any rod connected in between.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's an interesting question. What I believe is, your working is alright but the fallacy needn't exist. That is because this is not an electrostatic field. It is an electric field that is set up, which is non conservative. So it wouldn't yield proper results to directly subtract or add them. Work done in moving a charge through a given path, depends on the path as well, and hence O to A, and then to B, is different from O to B.

Comment: So, if we were to calculate $V_A - V_B$ it would be zero?

Comment: I suppose yes. Since the rod is thin, an EMF can't be set across its diameter. And hence as you had already stated in your question, it should be 0

Comment: A non conservative electric field is set up iff there is time varying magnetic field

Comment: I just verified it from other sources and as it turns out, the correct answer is $4.5B \omega$ (the first approach). The fallacy lies in the assumption that we can use that integral technique here since $\textbf{dl}$ we are considering here is a "part" of the rod, it is not an independent rod by itself.